# Как импортировать виртуальную машину из .vdi файла в VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Мне скинули файл виртуальной машины (Debian) в формате .vdi. Мне нужно развернуть эту же виртуальную машины у себя в VirtualBox, но при импорте виртуальных машин программа не видит файл .vdi. Что делать? Есть какие-то другие способы добавить эту ВМ себе?

Comment: Создать машину без виртуальных жестких дисков дисков, присоединить этот vdi как диск.

Comment: создал виртуальную машину, а как теперь присоединить к ней диск? Можешь скриншот скинуть с помеченной кнопкой на которую нажать нужно

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце: vdi - это образ виртуального жесткого диска, а не полный образ машины. Нужно создать виртуальную машину с нуля и присоединить этот образ диска.

Более развернуто: нужно создать виртуальную машину, на 3 шаге создания выбрать не "Создать новый виртуальный жесткий диск", а "Использовать существующий виртуальный жесткий диск", нажать на кнопку "Выбрать образ виртуального жесткого диска":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В следующем диалоге нажать кнопку "Добавить":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И дальше найти нужный файл vdi, выбрать его, и дальше в первом диалоге нажать кнопку "Создать". После этого запустить виртуальную машину.

Comment: Сделал все то же самое, но при запуске ВМ и выборе "Linux GNU/Debian" показывается просто черный терминал с мигающим курсором, ни на что не реагирует.

Comment: Возможно создана 32-битная машина вместо 64-битной, или еще какие-то нюансы

Comment: это фигня, не работает! при присоединении б/у диска будет ошибка по uuid

Comment: @vbox-sux это работает. На uuid будет ругаться, если вы один и тот же диск попробуете скопировать и к другой машине на этом же компе подключить.